# How to get a CSS animation to use GPU (Hardware Acceleration) instead of rendering with a CPU

Tags: html, css, gpu, css-animations

After reading an article on [CSS animations and how to build them](https://appcode.app/css-loader-animation-examples-and-code/), I have built my own, and I am trying to increase the performance of my CSS animation. My animation consists of three HTML elements that change widths to indicate media is playing.

Upon checking the timeline and resource tab in Chrome dev tools, I saw that the animation causes a high CPU load.

How could I convert the animation to GPU hardware acceleration instead of the browser renderer, which causes a high CPU load? I have read that you can use hardware acceleration that forces the animation to run on GPU.

*Is there a way to convert this (animating the width of the bar) to a GPU layer instead? Can I translate it somehow? or is there something better?*

There are 3 bars. This is the animation for it, not the styling.

```
@keyframes music {
  0%   { width:17px;  }
  10%  { width:11px;  }
  20%  { width:37px;  }
  30%  { width:30px;  }
  40%  { width:15px;  }
  50%  { width:10px;  }
  60%  { width:24px;  }
  70%  { width:17px;  }
  80%  { width:21px;  }
  90%  { width:32px;  }
  100% { width:17px;  }
}
.lines-ani {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.lines-ani .lines {
    animation: music 1.5s 2s ease-out alternate infinite;
}
.lines-ani .lines:before {
    animation: music 1.5s 1.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
}
.lines-ani .lines:after {
    animation: music 1.5s 2.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
}
```

Comment: No, `width:15;` is _not_ valid; that it is part of a keyframe doesn’t change that one bit.

Comment: @Cbroe that is a typo, I'll update it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid repainting and move the animation to GPU then you could use 3D transforms to produce the effect instead of animating the `width`. As mentioned in [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css), using 3D transforms mean that the browser would make the animation GPU accelerated.

> CSS animations, transforms and transitions are not automatically GPU accelerated, and instead execute from the browser’s slower software rendering engine. So what exactly forces the browser to swap to GPU mode? Many browsers provide GPU acceleration by means of certain CSS rules.
>
> Currently, browsers like Chrome, FireFox, Safari, IE9+ and the latest version of Opera all ship with hardware acceleration; they only use it when they have an indication that a DOM element would benefit from it. With CSS, the strongest indication is that a 3D transformation is being applied to an element.

Converting the animation into its 3D transform equivalent itself is not a big process. All that is needed is to set a initial `width` on all the three elements and convert the `width` within the `@keyframes` rules into their corresponding ratio value based on the initial width that is set.

A width animation is generally just a `scaleX` but `scale3d` is used since we need the animation to be moved to the GPU. Since `scale3d` takes 3 parameters (for scale in each of the three axes), we can provide 1 (initial scale) as the value for the other two axes. So, it would be `scale3d(x ratio, 1, 1)`.

For example, the `10%` frame provided in question has `width: 11px` setting and here is how we can get its equivalent `scale3d` value:

- Set an initial or starting `width` on the element. In the below snippet, I have set it as 17px.
- Get the scale ratio for the X-axis based on the initial width and the required width. That would be, 11px / 17px (which is 0.64).
- So, the equivalent 3D scale transform would be `scale3d(0.64, 1, 1)`.

```css
@keyframes color-bar {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale3d(0.64,1,1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale3d(2.17,1,1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.76,1,1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.88,1,1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(0.58,1,1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale3d(1.41,1,1);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale3d(1.23,1,1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale3d(1.88,1,1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
}
.lines-ani {
  width: 25vw;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.lines-ani .lines {
  position: relative;
  width: 17px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: color-bar 1.5s 2s ease-out alternate infinite;
}
.lines-ani .lines:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 125%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: color-bar 1.5s 1.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
}
.lines-ani .lines:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 250%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: color-bar 1.5s 2.5s ease-out alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='lines-ani'>
  <div class='lines'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** If you don't wish to use `scale3d` you could make use of `scaleX() translateZ(0)` also. The `translateZ(0)` is a 3D transform and the whole thing will still produce the same effect.

Comment: Ah sorry, that's the answer I was looking for. Thank you. I had to visually see what you done. Thanks!